# cannot add foreign key constraint in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

While creating 2 tables in phpmyadmin I am getting an error like this.

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

My table structures are

```
CREATE TABLE `iwd_storelocator_manufacturer` (
`entity_id`  int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
`code`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
`grayscale_image`  varchar(255) NULL ,
`color_image`  varchar(255) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `iwd_storelocator_manufacturer_to_store` (
`manufacturer_id`  int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`store_id`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
`preferred`  int NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`, `store_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `iwd_storelocator_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `iwd_storelocator_manufacturer` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Can you tell me whats the problem in it?

This is my iwd_storelocator_store table

[iwd_storelocator_store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekJ9a.png)

Comment: I've created these tables successfully, but without FK to iwd_storelocator_store. Maybe this table is reason of the problem?

Comment: Where's the structure of `iwd_storelocator_store` table?

Comment: my iwd_storelocator_store  table structure is given.

Comment: Pavel..You are right. I can also create without FK to iwd_storelocator_store . But I need that id also in my second table

Comment: edited my answer @Sheen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to know exactly what is wrong, you must check in `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

Use this query to find this out:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

Also, make sure that all the data types are the same: the data type of the child column must match the data type from the parent column.

If the problem is the order of creation of the tables (which can cause this error), just run `set foreign_key_checks=0` so you can create the tables in any order rather than having to create all the parents tables **BEFORE** the child tables.

Finally, make sure that the encoding is the same for all the tables.

EDIT: in your case, you should also give us the structure of `iwd_storelocator_store` table

**Now that we have your `iwd_storelocator_store` table, I think that you should create an index on `store_id` column as it is not the primary key of the table**